# Filling in triangles/Compiler error

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm trying to fill in a triangle with lines. The challenge is not to use fill polygon, but instead to use a loop and fill with lines. Anyway, I've yet to figure out the loop. I'm going to creates ints and use a for loop to add to them.

I'm still setting the rest up and I  get this absurd compiler error all over the place:

```
error: not a statement

error: ';' expected
```

It's weird because I already initialized the ints. There's ; in there.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Tri extends JApplet
  {


  public static void main(String[] args) 
     { 

         int 1x = 0;
         int 1y = 140;
         int 2x = 120;
         int 2y = 140;
         int 3x = 60;
         int 3y =0;

               public void paint (Graphics page)
               {

                  page.drawLine (1x, 1y, 2x, 2y); 
                  page.drawLine (2x, 2y, 3x, 3y);
                  page.drawLine (3x, 3y, 1x, 1y); 

               }

    }
   }
```

Comment: `import java.awt.*`? I hope you don't plan on using a `List` anywhere in your code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your variables cannot start with a number.

You cannot nest methods. (I think you might be thinking of nested classes, which is allowed)

You need to make sure the variables you declared are in scope.

```
public class App {
    int x1 = 0;           //<<<<<<------change your variable names
    int y1 = 140;
    int x2 = 120;
    int y2 = 140;
    int x3 = 60;
    int y3 =0;

public static void main(String[] args) 
     { 

       App app = new App();     //instantiate an instance
      app.paint(g);   //dunno where you get g, but paint needs to be its own method.




    }

   public void paint (Graphics page)
               {

                  page.drawLine (1x, 1y, 2x, 2y); 
                  page.drawLine (2x, 2y, 3x, 3y);
                  page.drawLine (3x, 3y, 1x, 1y); 

               }
}
```

Comment: I took out public static void main, and it runs.